# HTML structure in treeview with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview, html-lists

I need to display a HTML structure in a treeview. I found some jQuery treeview plugins but they generally require a list.

Let's take a simple HTML (nodes may have different tags, not only 'div'):

```
<div id="node1">
    <div id="node2">
        <div id="node3"></div>
        <div id="node4"></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

I want to display it like this:

node1

- node2

  - node3
  - node4

For now, i'm using this jQuery plugin: [treeview](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm)

So I need to convert the HTML to an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>node1
        <ul>
            <li>node2
                <ul>
                    <li>node3</li>
                    <li>node4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do this using jQuery? If you think a different approach would be better, please let me know.

Comment: Can you not do a string-replace in your source code editor?

Comment: It should work dynamically, a replace doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go...that was fun.  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/se4HF/4/)  - Updated to not be specific to `div` tags, and return an element, that could be turned into a `html` string.

```
$.fn.convertToUL = function(isTop) { 
    if(isTop==null) isTop=true;
    var ul=$("<ul>");
    var li=$("<li>");
    li.append($(this).attr("id"));
    var children=0;
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        ul.append($(this).convertToUL(false));
        children++;
    });
    if(children>0)
        li.append(ul);
    if(li.is(':empty'))
        return "";
    if(isTop)
        return $("<ul>").append(li);
    return li;
}

//to get text of elements use .wrap('<div/>').parent().html()
var ulElement=$("#node1").convertToUL();
alert(ulElement.wrap('<div/>').parent().html());
$("#node1").replaceWith(ulElement);
```

Comment: This is great Michael_B! except that I don't want to replace the existing HTML. I need it as a separate string. My question was not clear.

Comment: @Victor, I've modified it again to return as an element...and shown how to get that as a string if you'd like.